# Mongoose : "Invalid schema configuration : 'model' is not a valid type within the array"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose for node.js and MongoDB for the first time ever. I've tried following the documentation but it seems I have misdone something.

I am trying to create three collections (Tweet, Comments and Messages) within a cluster (is that a database ?) called Post. Following those models are a bunch of HTTP methods that I have yet to try out because of the error I receive.

The error is

> Invalid schema configuration : 'model' is not a valid type within the array

It's located on the lines that call for a model like :

> const Commentaire = mongoose.model("Commentaire", commSchema)

I've seen other questions with the same error but the fixes provided are not general enough, as this error must be quite common and easy to get.

Here is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Posts', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("connecté à Mongoose")
});

Schema = mongoose.Schema
//Commentaires sous les tweets
const commSchema = new Schema();
commSchema.add({
    id_comm:{ //id unique qui permet de référer le comm
        type: Number,
        required: true,    
    },             
    login:{ //le login de la personne qui envoie le comm
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    id_tweet:{ //l'id unique du tweet sous lequel le commentaire va
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    comm:{ //commentaire en question, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date:{ //date de l'envoie du message
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }                   
})
const Commentaire = mongoose.model("Commentaire", commSchema)
//Tweets
const tweetSchema = Schema();
tweetSchema.add({
    id_tweet:{ //id unique qui permet de référer le message
        type: Number,
        required: true,    
    },             
    user_id:{ //le login de la personne qui envoie le message
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    tweet:{ //tweet en question, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    titre:{ //titre du tweet, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date:{ //date de l'envoie du message
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    comms: { type: [Commentaire] }                
})
const Tweet = mongoose.model("Tweet", tweetSchema)
//Messages privés
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id_mess:{ //id unique qui permet de référer le message
        type: Number,
        required: true,    
    },             
    sender_id:{ //l'id de la personne qui envoie le message
        type: Number,
        required: true, 
    },
    ami_id:{ //l'id' de la personne qui reçoit le message
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    message:{ //message en question, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date:{ //date de l'envoie du message
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }                   
})
const Message = mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema)
```

I apologize for the comments in French, I'm not a native English speaker which makes understanding the documentation a bit harder for me. Those comments only exist to remind myself of which value represents what so please disregard that.

I thank you for your time. Have a good day.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @Someone Special is close, but you need to pass the Schema in, not the Model.

Change

```
comms: [Commentaries]
```

To

```
comms: [commSchema]
```

Comment: Thank you ! It is now working ! I'm having a hard time grasping the difference between a Schema and a Model so that's what I lacked.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Think of the Schema as the description of how the data can be stored and the Model as the actual container where data can be stored. Good luck on your coding journey!

Comment: Thank you. I was also having the same problem. Instead of parsing the schema, I had passed the class(which is created with Schema decorator).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to create sub document type, can u change the line commented below?

```
tweetSchema.add({
    id_tweet:{ //id unique qui permet de référer le message
        type: Number,
        required: true,    
    },             
    user_id:{ //le login de la personne qui envoie le message
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    tweet:{ //tweet en question, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    titre:{ //titre du tweet, sous forme de chaîne de caractère
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    date:{ //date de l'envoie du message
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    comms: { type: [Commentaire] } //<-- try this line                 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've corrected that, but I still get the same error on the "tweetSchema.add(" line.

Comment: another error is `const tweetSchema = Schema();`, you forgot to add the `new` word before schema

Comment: Indeed I did ! Thank you !